# Anylogic - Custom distribution with summed up values?

Tags: distribution, agent, anylogic

I need help with defining a custom distribution with Anylogic. I have a grid with 400 fields, each representing a geographical area. I measured the number of Clients per day in each field empirically (so I have a *sum* for each field).

Now I want to do a stochastic simulation. The number of generated agents (clients) is generated as a rate per day (as measured empirically as total over all fields). The number of the field should be assigned randomly as distribution, where "the probability that the client is generated in field x" equals "the number of clients in measured field x divided by the total number". I have these numbers as a table (database). The problem is that the Custom distribution block wants to read a table with all values (so that if field x has 5 clients per day, I would need to enter 5 times the number x).

Does anyone have a better idea how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Or do you know how to generate agents by database, with attributes by some probabilty?

PS: I want to generate the field ID, because there is more information attached to each field.

Edit: if I make a table with all the values listed x times, I cannot choose a value column:
[CustomDistribution for Start Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nByMG.png)

Comment: Can you clarify?  It seems like you describe the following:

Comment: a source block creating all clients (total over all fields), and then the custom distribution using the relative values to give you a probability.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want to do. Sorry, if my text is confusing.
 
I also tried this approach: creating a table, where the values are not summed up (as shown in the tutorial video). Here I have the problem, that I can choose my table, but there is no value column to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your custom distribution to "Continuous" with interpolation of "None".  For each value, you can have whatever you want in the weight column - this can be a precalculated sum.  The no interpolation will give you exactly one of the entered values, which *could* be a real number, but in this example are just discrete (1,2,3).

[image]

Comment: Yep, thank you. It works now with sums. Although where I call the distribution, I have to manually cast from double to int or it will give me an error. Doesn't do that by itself unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution to both problems:

1) Seemingly Anylogic cannot build a custom distribution from summed up values, as it does the sum by itself internally.

2) After creating the big table with over 20.000 values instead of the 400 sums, I could'nt choose a value column (see picture). I recreated the big table and changed the values from "f1" to "1" (String to int). And now it works. So Seemingly, Anylogic can only process intergers, but not Strings in its custom distribution database function.

Feel free to correct me, if this is wrong.

Comment: I think the database components of this question & answer are misleading.  AnyLogic help menu states that the custom distribution can be used for continuous values, discrete values, or option lists.  The custom distribution cannot use strings.  It does not have anything to do with the database aspects of linking a custom distribution to a database.

Comment: While I understand your argument, I don't think it is misleading. As someone who never used this function before, you can't know where the problem lies. As I'm reading tables (a database), it is a question of what can or cannot be written in the tables to make it work. The main point of my question was how to use the custom distribution, not how to use the database. The question was whether the custom distribution can read precalculated sums. The answer is no. Besides, I have not tagged it nor is it in the caption, so what would your suggestion to a better question be?

Comment: The custom distribution CAN use precalculated sums to determine probability/weight of something being returned.  The issue was not related to precalculated sums.  The issue was that you were passing in string values for the return value of the custom distribution. I recommend you change your answer, because #1 is not true.  The correct answer would be part of #2: "The custom distribution does not take strings for what should be returned.  I changed the values from "f1" to "1" and now it works."

Comment: As to your comment that your question/answer was not misleading because of the database link.  The answer you had originally posted, when I made my comment, referenced databases as the issue.  I think that your answer is now better, and less of a red herring towards databases as being the fundamental issue.

Comment: I should have clarified that. I had precalculated sums as integers in my first test, like the first column was the id of the field and the second column was the sum. I didn't find a solution to read these. 

You said: "The custom distribution CAN use precalculated sums to determine probability/weight of something being returned." 
If you know how that works please tell me, because I still don't know how to do that and you have not provided an answer to the original question.